# Kotlin multiple conditions with OR

Tags: kotlin, if-statement, conditional-statements, android-jetpack-compose, case

I have an "if" statement having 2 conditions. If just one of its 2 conditions is not equal, then it should show a specific text like below :

```
if (food != apple || food != orange ) {
    Text (text = "They are vegetables.")
}
```

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: Your condition is flawed.  One of those two conditions will ALWAYS be true.  If food is apple, then it cannot be orange.

Comment: Thanks Tim, your remarks helped me to find the asnwer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the correct answer : if (food != apple && food != orange ) {
Text (text = "They are vegetables.")}